# when I use a library(RODBC), a error message alert" unable to load odbcji32.dll"

Tags: r, rodbc

library(RODBC)
channel=odbcConnectExcel2007("d:/data/Salary.xlsx")  #when run this, it alert as " unable to load odbcji32.dll" and stop, how to slove the problem.

Comment: A quick search reveals [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c68fbeb7-9fae-4f43-a6a6-da1086bfdc01/unable-to-load-odbcji32dll-odbc-driver-for-microsoft-access-installation-problem-after-office?forum=accessdev)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your helping. I downloaded AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe and installed it.Then all is running rightly.